# Is there a way to get the iPhone model using sysctl?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, model, cpu

I need to get the model number, for example: for iPhone 6 the model I wanna get is N61AP not iPhone 7,2. I need this in objective-c. 
I've tried some ways, but all I get is the 'iPhone 7,2' :( 
If there is no way of gathering this, is there a way to get the CPU vendor? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try adding this (anywhere will do, app delegate perhaps):

```
+ (NSString *)model
{
    size_t size;
    sysctlbyname("hw.model", NULL, &size, NULL, 0);
    char *model = malloc(size);
    sysctlbyname("hw.model", model, &size, NULL, 0);
    NSString *modelString = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:model]; // could also use shorthand wrapper: '@(model)'
    free(model);
    return modelString;
}
```

For my iPad Air device, this gives me 'J71AP'.

Should you actually want something like the actual device name (i.e. 'iPhone7,2', or in my case, 'iPad4,1'), replacing "hw.model" with "hw.machine" will give it to you.