# How to check if device is Vision Pro - Xcode 15 Beta 4

Tags: swift, xcode, visionos

I have a video analysis app and i'm trying to make it compatible with visionOS. It crashes because camera is not allowed; Apple only allows to import videos from Photos.

So I would need to check on launch if the device runs visionOS to show the photos picker rather than the camera view, similarly to what I use right now to check if I'm on macCatalyst or iOS:

```
#if targetEnvironment(macCatalyst)
   print("We are in macOS Catalyst")
#else
   print("We are in iOS")
#endif
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would imagine it'd be `#if os(visionOS)`. Can't find it documented though.

Comment: I tried that before posting but it doesn't work...

Comment: Does anybody figure it out after release of vision pro?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found a workaround with a piece of code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30075200/4916939), created to detect iPhone/iPad models:

```
    func modelIdentifier() -> String {
    if let simulatorModelIdentifier = ProcessInfo().environment["SIMULATOR_MODEL_IDENTIFIER"] { return simulatorModelIdentifier }
    var sysinfo = utsname()
    uname(&sysinfo) // ignore return value
    return String(bytes: Data(bytes: &sysinfo.machine, count: Int(_SYS_NAMELEN)), encoding: .ascii)!.trimmingCharacters(in: .controlCharacters)
}
```

When calling it in viewDidLoad, it successfully detects the Vision Pro simulator as 'RealityDevice14,1'.

Comment: It remains to be seen which model identifier will be returned on a real Vision Pro device.

Comment: Sure, but it's unlikely Apple will break the established pattern here when it comes to the relationship between values in the simulator and actual device. And `14` is also consistent with M2-based Macs (_e.g. `Mac14,2`_). In lieu of proper API support from Apple (_equivalent of `ProcessInfo.isiOSAppOnMac`_), I don't see a better solution, so I would go with this (_perhaps using `sysctl` in place of `uname`, as illustrated in https://stackoverflow.com/a/36877687/21963209_).

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution doesn't seem to work on a real device. We don't have one to check for sure, but our app didn't pass a compatibility check at Apple - the app tries to use unavailable APIs which we have restricted on Vision Pro, but the device check fails.

Answer (score 5):

#### Compiler directives

Try `os(visionOS)` or `os(xrOS)`. At the moment both names are [correct](https://forums.swift.org/t/xros-or-visionos/65751).

```
#if os(visionOS)
   print("We are in visionOS")
#else
   print("We are NOT in visionOS")
#endif
```

Since [2023-09-18](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/revisionhistory/), `os(visionOS)` is the [officially documented way](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/statements/#Conditional-Compilation-Block).

Comment: Thanks, but that's the first thing I tried and it doesn't work. It always print the "We are in iOS" message. Even though I'm running in visionOS simulator, it detects it as iOS. Maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: It depends where you put your preprocessor macros. I use it inside ContentView (#else statement is automatically dimmed out).

Comment: I use it in the viewDidLoad method of a specific UIViewController, and it doesn’t work. UIdevice.model tells me it’s an iPad…

Comment: @CarlosBF The reason for this is that the UIKit app will run in iPad-compatible mode, whereas OS(xrOS) will return false.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you're **running your iOS app directly on visionOS**, without recompiling the code against the visionOS SDK, correct?

If so, the app is in **compatible mode**, and any conditional compile directives like `#if os(xrOS)` won't work. It's similar to an iOS app running on a Mac with Apple Silicon (check `ProcessInfo.isiOSAppOnMac`).

However, I haven't found a suitable API to determine if an iOS app is running on visionOS at runtime.

Forum Link: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/733029

**UPDATE**

1. `uname(&systemInfo)` works on simulator but NOT on a physical device. ❌

```swift
var systemInfo = utsname()
uname(&systemInfo) // "iPad13,4" returned on a physical device
```

2. Detect Camera ❌

```
UIImagePickerController.isCameraDeviceAvailable(.rear) // false on visionOS but also can be false for an restricted iOS device
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Gong. You were correct. It seems that there are no options right now to check if an iOS app is running on Vision Pro. The only viable option at this point is to compile adding Vision Pro as a new device rather than using the compatibility mode. It will likely break parts of the code though

Comment: Hi again Gong, check my updated accepted answer. I've found a piece of code that detects the Vision Pro simulator as "RealityDevice". It might be helpful. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

For everyone who is wondering, the device name for the real Vision Pro is `iPad13,4`, not `RealityDevice` as in simulator. It has a `.front` camera, but does not have a `.rear` camera for `UIImagePickerController.isCameraDeviceAvailable`.

This means we are unable to tell a difference between a real iPad and the Vision Pro. The only option is to use a combination of checks for identifier + camera and wait for an equivalent of `isiOSAppOnMac`.

Answer (score 1):

Actually it is not because camera is not allowed, it is because camera is not available on simulator. The best you can do, if you are building `visionOS` app using `iOS` SDK, you can check whether camera is available or not using [availability check](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimagepickercontroller/1619159-iscameradeviceavailable). This is actually much safer solution and works e.g. when camera is not available on some phone as well (iPhone simulator).

```
if UIImagePickerController.isCameraDeviceAvailable(.front) {
    ...
}
```

For more info see [WWDC 2023 video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2023/10094/?time=537).

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
if !UIImagePickerController.isCameraDeviceAvailable(.rear) {
    // Vision Pro
}
```

`.front` comes up with `true` but `rear` comes up with `false`. It is fallible of course but since iPads all have rear cameras it should work.